# Multiple conditions in formatting Excel cell

Tags: excel

I need to write a text into a cell, based on the value of another cell, for instance:

Cell G1 have value blank and H1 have value 0%; I need to write "In progress" into G1 cell when the percent value in H1 is more than 0%, "In progress" if the value is between 1-99%, and Completed if the value is equal to 100%.

One part is achivied using `=IF(H1<> 0%, "Work in progress", "To be started")`

But When I try to specify two conditions: `=IF(H48<> 0%, "In progress", "To be started", IF(H48= 100%, "Completed"))`

I got the error

> "you've entered too many arguments for this function"

What's wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could use

```
  =IF(ISBLANK(H1),"To be started",IF(H1=0," ",IF(H1<1,"In progress","Completed")))
```

You need to have IF(test condition, true result, false result) even if embedding another IF.

So with:

```
=IF(H48<> 0%, "In progress", "To be started", IF(H48= 100%, "Completed"))
```

test: `H48<> 0%`

True result: `"In progress"`

False result: `"To be started"`

Instead of embedding another If as a false result test you have added a non existent additional parameter after the False result.

```
IF(H48= 100%, "Completed")
```

I think you may have missed a condition result or at least some logic:

I think you want:

If empty then "To be started"

If 0 then "insert text here"

If <1 then "In progress"

Else "Completed" Though this could return Completed for a text value for example in which case you want another If = 1 then "Completed"

So maybe something like:

```
=IF(ISBLANK(H1),"To be started",IF(H1<1,"In progress",IF(H1=1,"Completed","Unknown")))
```

Or if you do want the zero test (as per comments) in:

```
=IF(H1=0,"To be started",IF(H1<1,"In progress",IF(H1=1,"Completed","Unknown")))
```

Comment: Hi QHarr, I've changed your condition in this way: =IF(H69<> 0, "In progress", IF(H69<1,"To be started", "Completed")), but the missing piece is that if I set the value to 100%, cell still remain "In progress"

Comment: because 100% <> 0 so true therefore it will return In progress. I think, as per my answer, that you are actually saying if the cell is empty then say To be started. My bottom formula is trying to account for the different scenarios/

Comment: Yes I understand; what I miss to say is that cell H always contains 0% so the formula =IF(ISBLANK(H1),"To be started",IF(H1=0," ",IF(H1<1,"In progress","Completed"))) don't work because of "ISBLANK", Can I specify something like =IF(EQUAL to 0....?

Comment: if H is always zero why do the test? But yes you can swop this for H1=0

Comment: I mean it's the 'start condition'!

Comment: I have put an edit in at the end which hopefully is what you mean. Hope I have understand. See last formula.

Answer (score 0):

Try,

```
=lookup(h1, {0, 0.01, 1}, {"", "In progress", "Completed"})
```

[image]

Comment: so much to learn :-( +1 Though should there be a to be started?

Comment: Thank you Jeeped; your formula works just with Completed, if the value is set to 1% or 0, the cell still blank!